# Pairwise comparison of survival curves

Tags: r, survival, multiple-comparisons, lsmeans

I'm working with data on  the effect of different diets and disease ratios in the survival of ant colonies, and I'm looking for a good way to compare the different treatments to the control (no disease feeding on control diet).

I'm using *coxme* to build the survival model, as it allows me to use random factors, such as the original colony and experimental colony due to experimental colonies being sub-colonieis from original larger nests. The model is built like this.

```
cx <- coxme(Surv(Day, Survival)~Setup * Treatment + (1|Box) + (1|Colony), data = sdat)
```

I've seen others using the *pairwise_survdiff* function from the survfit-package, but it doesn't allow me to use random factors in it, or at least not coded the way they are in *coxme*, and I can't seem to find any examples where it is used.

I'm wondering, whether I can use the *emmeans* function for this purpose, because it contains the trt.vs.ctrl. comparison I wish to use, and it does take in the *coxme* model with random factors.

```
emmeans(cx, trt.vs.ctrl~Setup*Treatment, adjust="mvt")
```

Any input would be highly appreciated because I wouldn't want to misinterpret my data due to my shortcomings in statistics.

Comment: It should be OK if your goal is to compare mean log hazard rates -- as that is what is estimated by these models.

Comment: Thank you again @RussLenth! I thought that it might be okay, but wasn't completely sure!